RTOS on ATtiny85, 8 bit MCU. Is it possible?
Everyone, I am working with ATtiny85 using Arduino IDE. Recently I was learning about RTOS. I want to ask if it possible to run RTOS on ATtiny85 microcontroller? According to my knowledge it may be possible using some other techniques? but not specifically RTOS. Am I right or not.
Is it possible or not, if not then is there any other way to run two or more tasks at the same time with out blocking the code?
I am using timer0 go generate an interrupt after certain time. now want to to another task using ATtiny85.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In my opinion it doesn't have enough RAM to be usable. But who knows.

For sure, it is possible. There are many RTOS available (also commercial ones) and it depends, which are supported, set of features on given HW and also how much resources it needs.
Demonstration, where are limits for micro controllers: It is also possible to run "normal" OS, like linux, on micro controller. Question is, if it is practical (boot time in hours for example). Nice reading https://dmitry.gr/?r=05.Projects&proj=07.%20Linux%20on%208bit (And there are more learning/hobby projects like this.

I am using arduino ide are there libraries similar to free rtos for 8 bit avr linke attiny85?

Yes, it is possible to make an RTOS that will run on Attiny85. All an RTOS needs is a data structure to represent each thread and a way of switching between them.
Here is an illustrative version of an RTOS that fits into even an ATTINY25 if it must...
http://www.femtoos.org/

thanks for the reply, i have seen the link to femto os, from there I think there is another workframe other than arduino ide for femto os, is it or not? can we use femto os on arduino ide? as i am programming attiny 85 with arduino ide.

moreover, ithink there are not enough material on the internet learning femto os.

I gave femtoos as an illustrative example to answer the question "RTOS on ATtiny85, 8 bit MCU. Is it possible?", showing that it is possible. But if all you want to do is to switch between two tasks, there are much easier ways. Check out the setjump and longjump function which can be used to do this. Here is one of many examples: https://notnik.cc/posts/async/
